# ArgumentNullException thrown by ContentManager.Load<Texture2D>()

Tags: c#, monogame, literals, argumentnullexception

I was trying to set up a static class for storing my textures in XNA/MonoGame, so I could have all loading code in one place and access the textures globally, but there's a bug that's killing me..

```
public static void Setup(GraphicsDevice gd, ContentManager manager)
{
        textures = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();

        // Cursor
        Texture2D t = manager.Load<Texture2D>("sprites/cursor"); // This line throws the exception
        textures.Add("cursor", t);
}
```

How can a string literal cause a ArugmentNullException? I'm used to Java where null is handled a bit differently, but this seems strange to me no matter...

Comment: The file exists and all that should be fine. The exact same line worked somewhere else, before I decided to do this global-access refactoring.

Comment: why do you think it's the string literal? Have you placed a breakpoint on the line to verify `manager` isn't null? Also, make sure this isn't being called before the main game class finishes it's initialization method. Loading content goes after initialization. Sometimes with static classes, it can be deceiving when the class is created so hopefully you're not calling this from your static class constructor.

Comment: I think you are right in that the cause is that it's calling Load() before everything is set up, but I still find it strange, since I'm calling Setup() from the Initialize() method in the Game class..
Anyway, I found a better solution to it all in the end, so all is good.
thanks for your help!